# Is there a 'Are you sure want to continue?' SQL Command?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have many SQL Server scripts.  But there are a few critical scripts that should only be run at certain times under certain conditions.  Is there a way to protect us from ourselves with some kind of popup warning?

i.e.  When these critical scripts are run, is there a command to ask the user if they want to continue?

(We've already made some rollback scripts to handle these, but it's better if they not be accidentally run at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such thing.

You can write an application (windows service?) that will only run the scripts as and when they should be.

The fact that you are even asking the question shows that this is something that should be automated, the sooner the better.

You can mitigate the problem in the meanwhile by using [`if`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) to test for these conditions and only execute if they are met. If this is a series of scripts you should wrap them in transactions to boot.

Answer (score 1):

One work-around you can use is the following, which would require you to update a value in another table:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc
AS

WHILE (SELECT GoBit FROM dbo.OKToRun) = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Waiting for GoBit to be set!', 0,1)
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
END

UPDATE dbo.OKtoRun
SET GoBit = 0

... DO STUFF ...
```

This will require you to, in another spid or session, update that table manually before it'll proceed.

This gets a lot more complicated with multiple procedures, so it will only work as a very short-term workaround.

Answer (score 0):

sql is a query language. does not have ability to accept user inputs.

only thing i can think of would be to have it @variable driven.  first part should update @shouldRunSecond = 1.  and the second part should be wrapped in a

```
if @shouldRunSecond = 1
begin
   ...
end
```

second portion will be skipped if not desired.

Answer (score 0):

The question is - where are these scripts located ?
If you have them as .sql file that you open every time before you run, then you can simply add some "magic numbers" before beginning of the script, that you will have to calculate every time, before you run it. In example below each time before you run your script you have to put correct date and minute into IF fondition, other wise script will not run

```
IF DATEPART(dd,GETDATE())!=5 or DATEPART(mi,(GETDATE()))!=43
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('You have tried occasionally to run your dangerous script !!!',16,1);
    RETURN
END

--Some dangerous actions
drop database MostImportantCustomer
update Personal set Bonus=0 where UserName=SUSER_SNAME()
```

If your scripts reside in stored procedure - you can add some kind of "I am sure, I know what I do" parameter, where you will always pass, for example Minute multiplied by Day.
Hote it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have seen batch scripts containing SQLCMD ..., so instead of running the .sql script from code or management studio, you could add a prompt in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I have (on limited occasion) created an @AreYouSure parameter that must be passed into a stored procedure, then put comments next to the declaration in the stored procedure explaining the danger of running said procedure.

At least that way, no RANDOs will wander into your environment and kick off stored procedures when they don't understand the consequences. The parameter could be worked into an IF statement that checks it's value, or it doesn't really have to be used at all, but if it must be passed, then they have to at least figure out what to pass.

If you use this too much, though, others may just start passing a 'Y' or a 1 into every stored procedure without reading the comments. You could switch up the datatypes, but at some point it becomes more work to maintain this scheme than it is worth. That is why I use it on limited occasion.